# How to display a resource value in a gridview column, depending on another column's value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, resources

Here's what I have *(working)*:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>                        
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Id" DataField="Id" SortExpression="Id">
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name" SortExpression="Name">
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:TemplateField>                        
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<% $Resources: Resource, strYes %>' />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Equals("name1",Eval("Name")) %>' />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
        <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

What I wanted is something like *(not working)*:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<% (Equals("a",Eval("Name"))) $Resources: Resource, strYes : $Resources: Resource, strNo  %>' />
```

but which I haven't found out how to make it work! (So, depending on a previous column's value, show one or the other Resource item).

Any suggestions to correct this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use the return value of a function as text for your label:

```
<asp:Label Text="<%# GetLabelText(Container.DataItem) %>" ID="Label1" runat="server" />
```

And then in the .cs file

```
protected string GetLabelText(object dataItem) {
    DataRowView dataRowView = (DataRowView)dataItem;
    string name = (string)dataRowView.Row["Name"];
    return "some string with some logic";
}
```